# Keep first value in date in resampling aggregations in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have values by minute and I am trying to resample them by hour. As they are stock prices I have the columns open and closed. When resampling I need in the open columns to keep the price from the first minute every hour...

It would be something like this if there was a `FIRST` aggregation function:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', date_) AS date_by_hour, 
FIRST("open") AS "open", MAX(high) AS high, MIN(low) AS low, LAST("close") AS "close", AVG(weighted_price) AS price
FROM btc_usd
GROUP BY 1
```

example:

```
open,high,low,close,date_
262.50,262.20,262.80,262.28,2015-01-27 16:22:00
262.20,262.20,262.28,262.28,2015-01-27 16:23:00
262.15,262.15,262.15,262.15,2015-01-27 16:24:00
262.15,262.15,262.15,262.15,2015-01-27 16:25:00
262.09,262.15,262.09,262.15,2015-01-27 16:26:00
262.07,262.20,261.87,262.28,2015-01-27 16:27:00
262.10,262.10,262.18,262.18,2015-01-27 16:28:00
262.10,262.10,262.18,262.18,2015-01-27 16:29:00
262.15,262.50,262.15,262.49,2015-01-27 16:30:00
```

would give:

```
open,high,low,close,date_
262.50,262.50,261.87,262.49,2015-01-27 16:00:00
```

UPDATE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON
( date_trunc( 'hour', date_ )) "open", date_
FROM btc_usd
ORDER BY date_trunc( 'hour', date_ ), date_
```

this gives the first and using `DESC` on close i can get the last

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: ok, i will do that

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have added an example.

Comment: Do you need every hour of every day, or only the hours mentioned?

Comment: I am also confused, is the max/min for the hour, or for the first minute of the hour?

Comment: I am aggregating by the hour, I have every minute now, but will aggregate getting one row per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `DISTINCT` and various window functions, `first_value()` and `last_value()` amongst others, that is.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       first_value("open") OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('hour', "date_")
                                 ORDER BY "date_"
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) "open",
       max("high") OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('hour', "date_")) "high",
       min("low") OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('hour', "date_")) "low",
       last_value("close") OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('hour', "date_")
                                 ORDER BY "date_"
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) "close",
       date_trunc('hour', "date_") "date_"
       FROM "btc_usd";
```

Comment: is it faster than a join with what i have updated in the question.

Comment: @SamuelNLP: Try it. I don't have your data, so I cannot tell for that.